# How does java compile interdependent classes?

Tags: java

There are two classes:

```
public class B {
    A obj = new A();
}
```

and

```
public class A {
    B obj = new B();
}
```

As we can see that **class A has reference to class B and vice versa**. So both classes need each other for successful compilation.

This seems to be a deadlock scenario, but eclipse is able to compile this. How does this work?